# Creating graphs from datasets

Tags: jquery, html

I am experimenting with a database driven web app.

What library / techniques is everybody using in order to create graphical statistics such as flow charts, pie charts and linear graphs etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [jQuery flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for sometime now. It is pretty feature rich and can be easily generated with data sent from a php file via ajax. Different kinds of plots, zooming, panning, onhover info; a lot of options are there.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Or if you want more complex system like charts plus widget and components, try [ExtJS 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3)

Or if you want a use it with jQuery, Prototype or MooTools, take a look at [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/)